# Redirecting all versions of URL to main site with 301 status code

Tags: apache-2.4, 301-redirect

I want to permanently redirect all requests starting with the following to https://www.example.com using 301 code.

http://example.com

http://www.example.com

https://example.com

How should I edit my apache config files? Or do it using .htaccess file?

I currently have this in my apache config for http site:

```
<VirtualHost 5.x.x.x:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

and this in my https config:

```
<VirtualHost 5.x.x.x:443>
    ServerName example.com
    Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com/

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/example.com.cert
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/example.com.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/example.com.bundle
    SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 5.x.x.x:443>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    DocumentRoot /home/example/public_html/public
    UseCanonicalName Off

    ...
    FULL CONFIG
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

But a Seo test website (woorank) says the URLs resolve to different addresses (In 3 first URLs which are redirected the unicode characters are encoded with lowercase, while in the 4th case which is not redirected, the uniocode characters are in uppercase?):

```
URL Resolve
Warning, no 301 redirects are in place to redirect traffic to your preferred example. Pages that load successfully both with and without www. are treated as duplicate content!
Not all versions of your page point to the same URL.

http://example.com/programming/253/%D8%AE%D8%B7%D8%A7%DB%8C-java.lang.NullPointerException-%D8%AF%D8%B1-%D8%AC%D8%A7%D9%88%D8%A7 
to  
https://www.example.com/programming/253/%d8%ae%d8%b7%d8%a7%db%8c-java.lang.NullPointerException-%d8%af%d8%b1-%d8%ac%d8%a7%d9%88%d8%a7

http://www.example.com/programming/253/%D8%AE%D8%B7%D8%A7%DB%8C-java.lang.NullPointerException-%D8%AF%D8%B1-%D8%AC%D8%A7%D9%88%D8%A7 
to  
https://www.example.com/programming/253/%d8%ae%d8%b7%d8%a7%db%8c-java.lang.NullPointerException-%d8%af%d8%b1-%d8%ac%d8%a7%d9%88%d8%a7

https://example.com/programming/253/%D8%AE%D8%B7%D8%A7%DB%8C-java.lang.NullPointerException-%D8%AF%D8%B1-%D8%AC%D8%A7%D9%88%D8%A7
to
https://www.example.com/programming/253/%d8%ae%d8%b7%d8%a7%db%8c-java.lang.NullPointerException-%d8%af%d8%b1-%d8%ac%d8%a7%d9%88%d8%a7

https://www.example.com/programming/253/%D8%AE%D8%B7%D8%A7%DB%8C-java.lang.NullPointerException-%D8%AF%D8%B1-%D8%AC%D8%A7%D9%88%D8%A7
to
https://www.example.com/programming/253/%D8%AE%D8%B7%D8%A7%DB%8C-java.lang.NullPointerException-%D8%AF%D8%B1-%D8%AC%D8%A7%D9%88%D8%A7
```

Thank you

Comment: Your configuration looks correct. Is Apache actually running with that configuration though?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Yes. There is no other config for this domain.  Perhaps Woorank is in mistake and everything is fine then.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: For simple cases like that, `RedirectPermanent` (that does not need the big `mod_rewrite` module) could be enough.